# Creating vectors of equal length in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am currently confused on why my vectors are off by the length of 1 when in this code. When I check both of the lengths my Y vector is always one off. Even though I think I specifically set it to be the exact length of vector t. Any suggestions?

```
func = @(y,t) y*sin(t);
for i = [1/4,1/8,1/16,1/32,1/64]
    [Y,t] = runge_kutta(-1,1,i,func);
    disp(length(Y));
    disp(length(t));
end

function [Y,t] = runge_kutta(y0,T,dt,f)
    t = 0:dt:T;
    Y = zeros(1,length(t));
    Y(1) = y0;
    for i = 1:length(t)
        k_1 = f(t(i),Y(i));
        k_2 = f(t(i)+0.5*dt,Y(i)+0.5*dt*k_1);
        k_3 = f((t(i)+0.5*dt),(Y(i)+0.5*dt*k_2));
        k_4 = f((t(i)+dt),(Y(i)+k_3*dt));
        Y(i+1) = Y(i) + (1/6)*(k_1+2*k_2+2*k_3+k_4)*dt;
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In the function `runge_kutta`, the for loop goes from 1 to `length(t)`, but you index `Y` using `i+1`, so when `i=length(t)`, the for loop appends a value to `Y` at index `length(t)+1`.

Answer (score 0):

The key is line 17 of your code.

See, in your runge_kutta function with input values that you specified, `t` is a 1x5 vector. Then, you enter into a for cycle, looping over values of i = 2, i = 3, i = 4, and lastly i = 5. When the loop gets to line 17, your `i = 5` and by running `Y(i+1) = Y(i) + (1/6)*(k_1+2*k_2+2*k_3+k_4)*dt;` you are adding an extra element to your Y vector, thus your `Y` is now 1x6.

I do not know the runge-kutta method, but if you want your `t` and `Y` to always have the same length, there are many ways to do that based on what you want to achieve. If you want to get rid of the last element of `Y`, you could insert something between your lines 16 and 17 that would look like this:

```
if i == length(t)
    break
end
```

This will terminate the loop right before adding an extra element to your `Y` in the last iteration of the for loop.

Comment: Weird idea, to add the condition inside the loop. Why not suggest to loop over `1:length(t)-1`? Or better yet, as is usual, over `2:length(t)` and change the indexing to use `i-1` and `i` inside the loop.

Comment: I guess there can be many solutions to the same problem :-) I admit that using `1:length(t)-1` would be easier. Mine works too though, and it being weird is subjective.